# Handle several view models int ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am working in an application that should evaluate a set of students through different activities.

An activity has a name, a description, some other properties and a set of questions like a "true or false questions", "multiple answer questions",
 "single answer questions", "order questions" and so on.

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5, Entity Framework (Code first) and C#.

**My question is what is the better aproach to handle the different view models?**

**The fact is that the question types could increase over the time and these types could vary a lot, e.g. drag and drop, order, true or false, single answer, multiple answer.**

Mi first aproach is:

(1) Create an abstract class with the common properties for each activity

```
abstract class ActivityViewModel {

    // Some cool properties like name, description, modification date time, .....
}
```

(2) Create several view models, each one with a different set of question types

```
class TrueOrFalseActivityViewModel : ActivityViewModel {

    ICollection<TrueOrFalseQuestion> myCoolQuestions;
}

class OrderActivityViewModel : ActivityViewModel {

    ICollection<OrderQuestion> myCoolQuestions;
}
```

(3) Create one view for each view model and a single Create Action with an ActivityViewModel as parametter.

The problem is that the post action in asp.net mvc controllers can not handle abstract classes.

Should I use?

(1) A single controller with several actions:

```
class MySuperController : Controller {

    // Get actions lies here

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(TrueQuestionViewModel viewModel) {
        // Some cool actions here

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(SingleAnswerViewModel viewModel) {
        // Some cool actions here

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MultipleAnswerViewModel viewModel) {
        // Some cool actions here
    }

}
```

(2) Several controllers, one per each activity depending on the type on question that it contains.

```
class MyTrueOrFalseActivityController : Controller  {

        public ActionResult Create(TrueQuestionActivityViewModel viewModel) {
            // Some cool actions here
        }

        public ActionResult Update(TrueQuestionActivityViewModel viewModel) {
            // Some cool actions here
        }

        // Several actions here..... 
    }

class MyOrderActivityController : Controller  {

        public ActionResult Create(OrderActivityViewModel viewModel) {
            // Some cool actions here
        }

        public ActionResult Update(OrderActivityViewModel viewModel) {
            // Some cool actions here
        }

        // Several actions here..... 
    }
```

**I need suggestions in order to favor the code reuse, keeping things simple as possible and handle incoming question types**

Comment: If an activity can contain collections of `TrueOrFalseQuestion`, `SingleAnswer` etc., then you should have an `ActivityViewModel` that contains properties for `Activity` and properties `List<TrueOrFalseQuestionViewModel>`, `List<SingleAnswerViewModel>` etc. One view model, one GET method and one POST method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

Have a single viewmodel that will store all the possible answer types. You can create interfaces to narrow down the types of questions/answers you want top deal with in the action method. e.g.

```
    public interface ITrueFalseQuestion
    {
        bool Answer1 { get;set; }
        bool Answer2 { get;set; }
    }

public class ActivityViewModel : ITrueFalseQuestion
{
    bool Answer1 { get;set; }
    bool Answer2 { get;set; }
}
```

Thus in the controller you can do this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Question(ActivityViewModel question)
{
    var g = question as ITrueFalseQuestion;
    g.Answer1 // Do stuff....
}
```

I think this approach might work for you, depending on how big `ActivityViewModel` ends up becoming,